# Remove a dictionary if a string in key value

Tags: python

How to remove a dictionary of a list that I have in JSON if there are characters in one of the keys:

```
for i in data:
    results = i["results"]
    if not results == []:
        for x in results:
        price_str = x["price_str"]
        if "await" in price_str:
            results.remove(x)
```

My input:

```
"results": [{
  "price_str": "results awaited",
  "marque": "samsung"
  },
  {
  "price_str": "sold",
  "marque": "apple"
  }]
```

Output that I want:

```
"results":[{
  "price_str": "sold",
  "marque": "apple"
  }]
```

Comment: it is not at all clear why the first dictionary gets removed and the second stays.. What is the rule?

Comment: If there is "await" in x["price_str"], I don't want to keep the first dictionnary.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way for removing an element from a list while iterating is iterate over a copy of the list: by doing so you can't get unexpected results because you are not editing the list you are iterating over.

```
data = {
    "results": [{
            "price_str": "results awaited",
            "marque": "samsung"
        }, {
            "price_str": "sold",
            "marque": "apple"
        }
    ]
}

for results in data.itervalues():

    # You don't need to check if the list is empty
    # The for loop doesn't start if the list is empty
    # if not results == []:

    # Iterates over a copy of the list. So when you modify the original
    # list, you do not modify the copy that you iterate over.
    for result in results[:]:
        price_str = result["price_str"]
        if "await" in price_str:
            results.remove(result)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dct = {'results' : [{
  "price_str": "results awaited",
  "marque": "samsung"
  },
  {
  "price_str": "sold",
  "marque": "apple"
  }]}

for entry, x in enumerate(dct['results']):
    if 'await' in x['price_str']:
        print(x)
        dct['results'].pop(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well

```
dct = {'results' : [{
  "price_str": "results awaited",
  "marque": "samsung"
  },
  {
  "price_str": "sold",
  "marque": "apple"
  }]}


items = dct['results']
y=[a for a in items if "await" not in a['price_str']]
```

y will have the filtered list of items. Then later you can reassign it to the dictionary if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Having this initial dict:

```
list = {
            'results': [
                {'marque': 'samsung', 'price_str': 'results awaited'},
                {'marque': 'apple', 'price_str': 'sold'}
            ]
       }
```

By using [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) you can get from the list the elements that fit or not with your condition. In your case, you can use also [find()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp) function to get the results that NOT FIT your search, so you will obtain the desired array:

```
>>> new_results = filter(lambda x: x['price_str'].lower().find("await") < 0, list["results"])
>>> new_results
[{'marque': 'apple', 'price_str': 'sold'}]
>>> list["results"] = new_results
>>> list
{'results': [{'marque': 'apple', 'price_str': 'sold'}]}
```

Hope it helps!